How to compute the 2D coordinate in the s-domain?
I am not sure if my question is a right question to ask or not since I am still learning about Laplace Transform and S-Domain.
If we have 2D coordinates (x,y) in the spatial domain (i.e., Euclidean space), how we can compute/transform the coordinates to the s-domain (as complex numbers).
For example,in the case of 1D data, we have 10 time points in the time domain as follows:
tensor([1.0000e-04, 1.0110e-02, 2.0120e-02, 3.0130e-02, 4.0140e-02, 5.0150e-02,
        6.0159e-02, 7.0169e-02, 8.0179e-02, 9.0189e-02], device='cuda:0')

and then using the NeuralLaplace library, we can compute the coordinates in the s-domain using the following command:
# Cosine 
def fs(so):
    return 1/ 0.5+so**2  # Laplace solution

def ft(t):
    return torch.cos(t)   # Time solution

# Split evaluation of s points out from that of the line integral (should be the exact same result as above)
decoder = FixedTablot(ilt_reconstruction_terms=s_recon_terms).to(device)
t0 = time()
s, _ = decoder.compute_s(t)   # equivalent time points in s domain
fh = fs(s)
f_hat_t = decoder.line_integrate(fh, t)
print(
    "FixedTablot Loss (Split apart):\t{}\t| time: {}".format(
        np.sqrt(torch.nn.MSELoss()(ft(t), f_hat_t).cpu().numpy()), time() - t0
    )
)

As has been shown in this link.
In the case of 2D coordinates for the 2D data, how can I obtain the computation of coordinates in the s-domain?
I would appreciate it if there is any guide with this or if there is any other library and resources that I can use it for this purpose.
How this can be computed?

For samples signals, the Z-Transform is used and is equivalent to the Laplace Transform for discrete time.
That said, the two dimensional Z Transform is detailed here:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2D_Z-transform
